# In a regression task, how do I find which independent variables are to be ignored or are not important?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

In the regression problem I'm working with, there are five independent columns and one dependent column. I cannot share the data set details directly due to privacy, but one of the independent variables is an ID field which is unique for each example. 
I feel like I should not be using ID field in estimating the dependent variable. But this is just a gut feeling. I have no strong reason to do this. 
What shall I do? Is there any way I decide which variables to use and which to ignore?

Comment: ID variables are not *features*, hence they should indeed not be used for building ML models.

Comment: Without the non-feature ID, there are four columns. Make four regressions, each without one of the features, and compare to the results of fitting all four columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I agree with [@desertnaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685471/desertnaut). Id attribute does not seem relevant when creating a model and provides no help in prediction.

The term you are looking for is **feature selection**. Since it's a comprehensive section so I would just tell you the methods that are mostly used by data scientists.

As for regression problems you can try **correlation heatmap** to find the features that are highly correlated with the target.

> sns.heatmap(df.corr())

There are several other ways too like PCA,using tree inbuilt feature selection methods to find the right features for your model.

You can also try [James Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436862/james-phillips) method. *This approach is limited since model time complexity will increase linearly with the features*. But in your case where you've only four features to compare you can try it out. You can compare the regression model trained with all the four features with the model trained with only three features by dropping one of the four features recursively. This would mean training four regression models and comparing them.

Comment: As I noted, with four columns an exhaustive search to eliminate one feature would nean would mean running four regressions.

Comment: Yes I was exactly looking for feature selection methods for regression and didn't use right term in the question. Thanks for pointing in correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

According to you, the ID variable is unique for each example. So the model won't be able to learn anything from this variable as with every example, you get a new ID and hence no general patterns to learn as every ID only occurs once. 
Regarding feature elimination, it depends. If you have domain knowledge, based on that alone you can engineer/ remove features as needed. If you don't know much about the domain, you can try out some basic techniques like Backward Selection, Forward Selection, etc via Cross Validation to get the model with the best value of the metric that you're working with.

Comment: The data has only four columns, these techniques seem too much for the problem - as I noted, it is simpler to use feature elimination than bother with all of that because exhaustive search to eliminate one feature means running four regressions.